# Linker command failed: duplicate symbol for architecture i386

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, linker

I added the XYPieChart folder into my Swift project on XCode 6 but now I'm getting this "Apple Mach-O Linker Error":

```
duplicate symbol _main in:
/Users/ansariha/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Juxta-bjrfrzoyetsowibjdgpcxtesgwtg/Build/Intermediates/Juxta.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Juxta.build/Objects-normal/i386/AppDelegate-EE692B7EDFB39C7A.o
/Users/ansariha/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Juxta-bjrfrzoyetsowibjdgpcxtesgwtg/Build/Intermediates/Juxta.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Juxta.build/Objects-normal/i386/main.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Below that it says "1 duplicate symbol for architecture i386" and then below that, the error: "Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)".
Has anyone ever seen this before?

Answer (score 2):

Go to your project Bundle in xcode -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources
Check whether one of the files are added twice or not. This might be the case where such things happen. 
Your `AppDelegate` might be added twice. Remove one of them.

**Updated:**

Some time you accidentally importing the .m file instead of the .h due to which this error comes. Please check and If this is not the reason, then perform the following steps

1- Check Build phases in Target settings.

2- Go to compile source section.

3- Check if any file exists twice or once.

4- If file exist twice delete one.

5- Build again.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs duplication of file in your project. click on The Project Navigator and search Duplicate file. in your project duplication of `Appdelegate` class or `main`. Remove one of file from your project.

[image]